# iPhone xCode Insert Into mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, iphone, xcode, insert

Im battling to get this inserted into mySQL database. The connection doesnt have to be secure of anything as its just a proof of concept for a project. Im working with the following php file. Your help would be greatly appreciated as this is really frustrating me.

```
<?php

$host = "localhost"; //Your database host server
$db = "CrossfitPotch"; //Your database name
$user = "root"; //Your database user
$pass = "root"; //Your password

$deadlift = $_GET['deadlift']; 
$username = $_GET['username']; 

$con = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass) or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db($db,$con) or die(mysql_error()); 

$sql="INSERT INTO CFP (Deadlift) VALUES ('$_GET[deadlift]') WHERE Email = '$username'";
//$sql="INSERT INTO CFP (Deadlift) VALUES ('$_GET[deadlift]')";
$res = mysql_query($sql,$con) or die(mysql_error());


mysql_close($con);
if ($res) {
    echo "success";
}else{
    echo "faild";
}// end else

?>
```

My Xcode inserting method looks like this:

```
-(IBAction)insert:(id)sender
{
    // create string contains url address for php file, the file name is phpFile.php, it receives parameter :name
    NSString *url= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost/Justin_Test/Deadlift.php?username=%@", @"j@cfp.com"];
    // to execute php code
    NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: url]];
    NSString *AddDeadlift = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost/Justin_Test/Deadlift.php?username=%@&username=%@&deadlift=", _NameOfUser.text, _UserDeadlift.text];
    [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:AddDeadlift]];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Did the following to post to the mySQL. wanted to just add a answer incase others come across this. Firstly assign the textboxes with the data to your header file. Create a Click Event assigned to the button. My PHP file looks like this:

```
<?php

$host = "localhost"; //Your database host server
$db = "CrossfitPotch"; //Your database name
$user = "root"; //Your database user
$pass = "root"; //Your password

$deadlift = $_GET['deadlift']; 
$username = $_GET['username']; 

//$deadlift = 10; 
//$username = 'j@cfp.com';

$con = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass) or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db($db,$con) or die(mysql_error()); 

$sql = "UPDATE CFP SET Deadlift =  '$deadlift' WHERE Email = '$username';";

//$sql="INSERT INTO CFP (Deadlift) VALUES ('$_GET[deadlift]') WHERE Email = '$username'";
//$sql="INSERT INTO CFP (Deadlift) VALUES ('$_GET[deadlift]')";

$res = mysql_query($sql,$con) or die(mysql_error());


mysql_close($con);
if ($res) {
    echo "success";
}else{
    echo "faild";
}// end else

?>
```

And my event "insert" looks like the following with a alert message for blank fields:

```
-(IBAction)insert:(id)sender
{

    if([[self.txtName text] isEqualToString:@""] || [[self.txtWeight text] isEqualToString:@""])
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No Weight Entered"
                                                        message:@"Please Enter A Weight To Add"
                                                       delegate:nil
                                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss"
                                                        otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    } else
    {
    NSString *AddDeadlift = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost/Justin_Test/Deadlift.php?username=%@&deadlift=%@", txtName.text, txtWeight.text];
    [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:AddDeadlift]];
    }
}
```